# Are good kernels trigonometric polynomials?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, trigonometric-series

We know :
Definition: A kernel $K_n$ is 'good' if they are integrable and satisfy the following conditions:

1. $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}K_n(x)dx=1$
2. $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|K_n(x)|dx\le A$ for some $A>0$
3. For every $\eta>0$,
   $$\int_{|x|\ge\eta}|K_n(x)|dx\to0\text{  }\text{ }\text{ as } n\to0$$

My question is Are all good kernals trigonometric polynomials, and if so:
Is the convolution of a good kernal with a $2\pi$ periodic function a trigonometric polynomial?

Comment: No, of course not. For example, take $K_n(x) = k_ne^{-nx^2}$, where $k_n$ are positive constants take so that integral of $K_n(x)$ is $1$ are "good" kernels. Regarding the second question, yes it is true, it follows directly from the definition of convolution.

Comment: @Salcio I can't see how the convolution of a good kernal with a 2π periodic function a trigonometric polynomial for the definition of the convolution.